# No Module Named 'coremltools' Reoccurring Issue

Tags: python, macos, coremltools

I am following a project where I am create a new virtual environment (https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/installation#) using python commands.  I have both 2.7 AND 3.6 installed on my machine (mac).  I have followed the steps in order on the tutorial, but I am getting a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coremltools.'  I have already installed the package and I have incorporated the import statements on the file:
My code is this:

```
import coremltools as ct

caffe_model = ('oxford102.caffemodel', 'deploy.prototxt')

labels = 'flower-labels.txt'

coreml_model = ct.converters.caffe.convert(

    caffe_model,
    class_labels=labels,
    image_input_names='data'


)

coreml_model.save('FlowerClassifier.mlmodel')
```

commands used:
python convert-script.py -this is the python file I am running
pip install coremltools
source coremltools-venv/bin/activate
python -m venv coremltools-venv -created the environment

An image of the terminal is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsWk2.png)

I am lost on why the module is still not recognized.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coremltools'

Comment: Does `python3 convert-script.py` work?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you install the package into the venv ? activate first, then `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: Hopefully you are always using python 3.6, and never 2.7. Please show us the output of `$ which python`, `$ python --version`, and `$ python -m site`. Then do `$ python -m pip install coremltools` and `$ python -c 'import coremltools'`, reporting any errors that happen.

Comment: @TimRoberts looks like the module error is gone, however there is a new error AttributeError: module 'coremltools.converters' has no attribute 'caffe'... there is actually documentation on how to exactly do this here with the script: https://www.wwt.com/article/convert-a-caffe-model-to-core-ml-format ; seems like all the code is correct for the script so I'm guessing it's a package/versioning error?

Comment: @J_H so I used the command python3 convert-script.py and the error I am now getting is AttributeError: module 'coremltools.converters' has no attribute 'caffe'.   python --version
Python 3.9.6 in the virtual environment, true for the site command and I have run all the other commands in the environment

Comment: @J_H Someone also had the exact same problem on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/ruyl12/could_someone_help_me_with_converting_caffe_model/ it looks like caffe seems to be deprecated?